# How to get the highest date for each register after left join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, join, max

I have two tables (user and log) in mysql.

```
USER TABLE

id     email            name      status
--    -------          ------    --------
1     "x@domain.com"   "Carlos"     1
2     "c@domain.com"   "Marie"      1
3     "k@domain.com"   "Jason"      1



LOG TABLE

id      time                    user_id      
--     -------                  -------
123    "2020-09-07 08:05:03"      1
124    "2020-09-07 08:32:21"      2
125    "2020-09-09 09:01:46"      1
126    "2020-09-07 11:05:03"      3
```

I would like to get all the users and its last log in for each one. Then, I have this query:

```
SELECT 
      user.id,
      user.name,
      user.email,
      MAX(log.time) as time
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN log on user.id = log.user_id
WHERE user.status_id = 1 
GROUP BY user.id 
ORDER BY log.time DESC
```

The query returns all the users with its log (null if there is no log for the user) but the log is not the last of the user. May somebody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when i try above query, i get two errors. 1) There is a ','  just before the `FROM`.   2) I get   `ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.log.time' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` Because you are not getting this error, you should ask yourself on what information will this `ORDER BY` do the ordering? If it is on `log.time` then this is pretty useless, because you only select `max(log.time)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very little you need to change to make your query work (apart from two typos - extra comma and status vs status_id):

The `order by` clause does not make any sense, since the resultset does not have `log.time` field, it only has `max(log.time)`, so that's you need to order on and no need to use CTEs or subqueries - as long as you do not want to include additional columns from the `log` table:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` INTEGER primary key,
  `email` VARCHAR(14),
  `name` VARCHAR(8),
  `status` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO `user`
  (`id`, `email`, `name`, `status`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'x@domain.com', 'Carlos', '1'),
  ('2', 'c@domain.com', 'Marie', '1'),
  ('3', 'k@domain.com', 'Jason', '1');

CREATE TABLE log (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `time` VARCHAR(21),
  `user_id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO log
  (`id`, `time`, `user_id`)
VALUES
  ('123', '2020-09-07 08:05:03', '1'),
  ('124', '2020-09-07 08:32:21', '2'),
  ('125', '2020-09-09 09:01:46', '1'),
  ('126', '2020-09-07 11:05:03', '3');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
      user.id,
      user.name,
      user.email,
      MAX(log.time) as time
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN log on user.id = log.user_id
WHERE user.status = 1 
GROUP BY user.id 
ORDER BY max(log.time) DESC;
```

Result:

```
| id  | name   | email        | time                |
| --- | ------ | ------------ | ------------------- |
| 1   | Carlos | x@domain.com | 2020-09-09 09:01:46 |
| 3   | Jason  | k@domain.com | 2020-09-07 11:05:03 |
| 2   | Marie  | c@domain.com | 2020-09-07 08:32:21 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` is one sensible approach here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time DESC) rn
    FROM log
)

SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.name,
    u.email,
    t.time
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN cte t ON u.id = t.user_id
WHERE
    u.status = 1 AND t.rn = 1
ORDER BY
    t.time DESC;
```

Comment: This is not required as long as the OP needs only the max of time from the log table.  Simple group by and max will do. The problem is with the ordrr by clause. If this was the solution, then the question would be a duplicate one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.*, l.*
FROM user
JOIN log ON user.id = log.user_id
JOIN ( SELECT user_id, MAX(time) time
       FROM log
       GROUP BY user_id ) log1 ON log.user_id = log1.user_id AND log.time = log1.time
```

Applicable for MySQL 5.x

Comment: This is not required as long as the OP needs only the max of time from the log table. Simple group by and max will do. The problem is with the ordrr by clause. If this was the solution, then the question would be a duplicate one.

Comment: @Shadow *OP needs only the max of time from the log table* I see *I would like to get all the users and **its last log** in for each one.* Maximal time only is not enough for OP. Or what he need differs from what he tell...

Comment: The other fields from the user table are functionally dependent on the user.id field, thus do not need to be listed in the group by list from v5.7. Since these fields are in the user table, you can simply list those fields in the group by clause in v5.6 and previous versions. Your solution is needed only if additional fields are required from the log table.

Comment: *if additional fields are required from the log table.* Yes, I understand OP's task in this form.